# R equivalent of Python's dask

Tags: python, r, dask

Is there an equivalent package in R to Python's `dask`? Specifically for running Machine Learning algorithms on larger-than-memory data sets on a single machine.

Link to Python's `Dask` page:
https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

From the Dask website:

> Dask natively scales Python
>
> Dask provides advanced parallelism for analytics, enabling performance
>   at scale for the tools you love
>
> Dask's schedulers scale to thousand-node clusters and its algorithms
>   have been tested on some of the largest supercomputers in the world.
>
> But you don't need a massive cluster to get started. Dask ships with
>   schedulers designed for use on personal machines. Many people use Dask
>   today to scale computations on their laptop, using multiple cores for
>   computation and their disk for excess storage.

Comment: Please explain what `dask` does, and post a small (Python) sample of what you want to achieve - I'd guess only a minority of R programmers know specific Python packages by heart.

Comment: While none of them haveas sexy a website as `dask`, you can choose between `parallel`, and a combination of `foreach` with `doParallel`.

Comment: see the [high-performance computing task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) for starters

Comment: I made some good experience with the `ff` package.

Comment: the equivalent is {future}

Answer (score 8):

I am developing a simple library called [`disk.frame`](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame) that has the potential to take on `dask` one day. It uses the `fst` file format and `data.table` to manipulate large amounts of data on disk. As of now, it doesn't have a cluster module but given that it uses `future` in the background and `future` can have cluster back-ends, it is a possibility in the future.

There is also [multidplyr](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr) in the works by Hadley and co.

Currently, I have used disk.frame successful to manipulate datasets with hundreds of million rows of data and hundreds of columns.

If you willing to look beyond R then JuliaDB.jl in the Julia ecosystem is something to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

As a general matter, R, in its native use, operates on data in RAM. Depending on your operating system, when R requires more than the available memory, portions are swapped out to disk. The normal result is thrashing that will bring your machine to a halt. In Windows, you can watch the Task Manager and cry.

There are a few packages that promise to manage this process. RevoScaleR from Microsoft is one.  It is not open source and is not available from CRAN. I am as skeptical of software add-ons to R as bolt-on gadgets that promise better fuel economy in your car.  There are always trade-offs.

The simple answer is that there is no free lunch in R.  A download will not be as effective as some new DIMMs for your machine. You are better off looking at your code first.  If that doesn't work, then hire a properly-sized configuration in the cloud.

Comment: More kudos for dask for doing this well in python :)  Note that the dask distributed scheduler is language agnostic, and in theory could be called from R (there has been a Julia POC).

Answer (score 2):

I think worths take a look to Apache Arrow project (https://arrow.apache.org/) and its integration with several languages, among them, R (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/)

I have tested the example on 112 million rows, and it works amazingly fast!

Answer (score 1):

As I came across this question, I felt it was important to address this issue, as Dask does not exist in R. It is also difficult to find an alternative to it. However, R also provides good solutions. Below I address some:

1. Always read dataframes using `data.table::fread()` function. This is reads the data in an out of RAM mode.
2. Use the `ff` or `bigmemory` packages if your data frame is not extremely big. Otherwise, you may use the `matter` package. Below is a link to the matter package documentation:

https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/matter/man/matter.pdf

What is nice about the `matter` package is that it allows chunking data and delayed pre-processing, which is exactly what `Dask` does. You can use the `verbose = TRUE` argument to see the chunks while being processed. I would say this is quite similar to the client dashboard of `Dask`. To get the best out of this, set `BPPARAM = bpparam()` while performing `chunkApply()`. An example would be like this:

```
## Operate on elements/rows/columns
chunk_apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...,
simplify = FALSE, chunks = 20, outpath = NULL,
verbose = TRUE, BPPARAM = bpparam())
```

You can also check for the registered bpparam using:
`BiocParallel::registered()`
or register one yourself, for example `MulticoreParam()` if you are on `Linux` or `macOS`.

As for the **FUN** argument, you can write a custom function and plug it in, say `function(x){SomeTasksOn(x)}`.

This method has been extensively used in the Cardinal package to process huge biological datasets that are way too large to process. An example workflow includes:

http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/vignettes/CardinalWorkflows/inst/doc/MSI-classification.html#pre-processing

They also tried to do this using regularized regression with neighborhood convolution, then extract relevant features per class of interest. It works pretty well and fast.

To get a view of why and how it does it well, I would suggest this article (Link: https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/33/19/3142/3868724), where they compare matter to `R matrices, bigmemory , ff` to perform tasks like `glm`, and `lm`.

[image]

So, I would suggest to give it a try and see if it helps with processing big data.